# Ubuntu 22.04 Auto Timezone is wrong

Tags: timezone, location

My location service setting is on, and I can get my correct location on Google Maps.

But when I turn on auto timezone, it will set the timezone from PST to MST, and I am not even near any MST region.

I tried to turn it off and set it to PST manually then turn it back on, but it still set the timezone to MST.

Comment: How is this related to ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6, Sorry, forgot to include my OS version, it's Ubuntu 22.04, just added it to the title.

Comment: I'm in Asia and Ubuntu automatic timezone always put me in US time.